# Как избавиться от лишней переменной в Makefile?

Tags: windows, makefile

Функция `wildcard` в сочетании с шаблоном для поиска файла позволяет найти нужные файлы, но список файлов получается в unix-стиле, с разделителем /. При переработке такого Makefile под Windows приходится делать две переменные:

```bash
TMPS:=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
SOURCES:=$(TMPS:$(SRC)/%.cpp=$(SRC)\\%.cpp)
```

По-хорошему, переменная `TMPS` вообще не нужна, но у меня не получилось сделать так, чтобы работало, если на место неё подставить выражение с `wildcard`. Как такое сделать?

**UPD**

В принципе, сейчас я это делаю таким образом:

```bash
SOMEVAR=someexpression
SOMEVAR:=someexpression2($SOMEVAR)
```

Но можно ли это сделать одной строкой?

Comment: Эм.. Вроде бы винде вполне нормально живётся с `/` в путях. Уверен, что надо заменять на ``\``?

Comment: А нельзя ли использовать gulp, rake, invoke, любой другой инструмент? На полноценном языке программирования было бы легче всё это сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Substitution references](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html#Substitution-Refs) работают исключительно с переменными. По сути они - синтаксический сахар [для функции `patsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html), которую можно использовать напрямую:

```
$(patsubst pattern,replacement,$(var))
```

Код выше это то же самое что ниже:

```
$(var:pattern=replacement)
```

В вашем примере это будет так:

```
SOURCES:=$(patsubst $(SRC)/%.cpp,$(SRC)\\\\%.cpp,$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp))
```

(Другой вопрос зачем это делать, должно и так же, нет?)

Comment: Только четыре слеша не надо, у меня первый слеш экранирует второй, чтобы тот не экранировал процент.

Comment: У меня только с четырьмя заработало почему-то, но если у вас с двумя работает - то и замечательно.